# Eclipse Device Chooser cant find my Dell Streak

Tags: android, eclipse, driver, device, adb

Im starting to develop for android and i would like to test my aplication in my Dell Streak, its running 1.6 and my OS is Windows 7.

According to this link http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html all that i need to do to deploy on my device is:

- Declare your application as
  debuggable in your manifest: i ready
  have added that to may application 
  `<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">`
- Enable USB Debugging on your device:
  i already activated in application >
  development > USB debbuging
- Ensure that your development computer
  can detect your device when connected
  via USB: I already install the drive
  to de point that i get "The best
  driver software for the device is
  already installed" and i can see my device conected in windows explorer

But i dont get have any ADB Interface in computer > device manager, i have it under Portable Devices. Beside that i have everything correct, but Eclipse Device Chooser has no Android device listed.

What can i do to have my Streak listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compatible Android USB Driver for Windows 7 is `not yet Released`. Check the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html). There was instructions to install only in Windows/Vista OS.