# Dell Streak : Setting it up to use in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have just got my Dell Streak and updated it to Android 2.2.

I got Eclipse setup with Android etc and have used it with other android phones.

However when I plug in my dell streak and turn on USB debugging.  Nothing comes up in Eclipse.

Is it because its picked up the device as a Dell Streak and not installed a ADB driver?

Comment: What OS do you use? Also, the following link might help[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732250/eclipse-device-chooser-cant-find-my-dell-streak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing the driver for dell streak. Check out the android developer site for links to different OEM drivers http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have your phone plugged into your computer and in debug mode. Are you saying you don't see your phone come up in AVD when you try to run your app in Eclipse??

If you have the Android SDK installed and Eclipse configured correctly you should be able to see your phone.

try this and let us know what you get. If you can't find ddms you don't have your path set correctly.

```
apesa@superGLTS:~/Development/Signed_APKs$ ddms
```

You should get Dalvik Debug Monitor and your phone should show up in the upper right corner window.

If not, your phone may have to be config'd a bit. As an example HTC phones need a USB Permissions auth file in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like it's a driver issue. Have you installed Dell PC Suite? I'm pretty sure that doing so will install the driver you need.

Otherwise, there you should be able to get the driver by itself elsewhere. This tutorial is for installing a custom ROM, but the first part walks through installing the ADB driver for the Streak

http://streakdroid.com/?page_id=78

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First, If you want to check whether the device is attached or not, you should run **`adb devices`** at the command prompt which will list all the devices(including emulator if connected).

Second, [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) is the android sdk detail, from where you will easily find out enough information on: **`Setting up a Device for Development`**,